# uwsgi process died with "libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work"

Tags: python, gcc, centos, uwsgi

uWSGI runs on CentOS 5 with python2.6

Sometimes, the below errors show in uwsgi log:

> libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work DAMN !
>   process 2474 died :( trying respawn ... Respawned uWSGI worker (new
>   pid: 6328)

I searched on web, but I don't understand why this happens.

More info:

> locate libgcc
>   /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1 
>   /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
>   /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1 
>   /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/libgcc.a
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/libgcc_eh.a
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/libgcc_s_32.so
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/32/libgcc.a
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/32/libgcc_eh.a
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/libgcc.a
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/libgcc_eh.a
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/libgcc_s.so
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/32/libgcc.a
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/32/libgcc_eh.a
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/32/libgcc_s.so
>   /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux/2.96/libgcc.a
>   /usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux/2.96/libgcc_eh.a
>   /usr/sbin/libgcc_post_upgrade /usr/share/doc/libgcc-4.1.2
>   /usr/share/doc/libgcc-4.1.2/COPYING.LIB

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm facing this very same problem now on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4):

This error is generally because uwsgi configuration. Lets you "limit-as" becomes larger, or remove the restrictions. But I also strongly recommend that you use [cgroup](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/UseCgroups)

Comment: And you should start uwsgi with user id and group id, e.g. --uid www-data --gid www-data